# Replace key and value in an associative array and keep elements order

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
$columns = [
        'id'=>'Id',
        'status'=>'Status',
        'created_at'=>'Created At'
];
```

and I want to replace key and value `'status'=>'Status'` with `'payment_status'=>'Payment status'`;
I know that I can delete element by key using `unset($columns['status'])` and add the new element to the end or to the beginning of the array. But I want to keep elements order so the new element should be added after `id'.

Comment: Why is the order so important?

Comment: @NigelRen because there are columns for a table in this array. I use foreach to display them and `payment_status` column should be after `id`

Comment: The order of the items shouldn't make any difference. https://3v4l.org/RqBv7

Comment: @Andreas I don't use multidimentional array. I use datatables and in my array key is a name of a column and value is a label.

Comment: If it's not multidimensional then I can not understand why you need them in a specific order. You just echo the correct item at the correct place. Don't loop if you don't have to, it's just creates a chance for a bug to find its way in.

Comment: @Andreas  this peace of code displays table: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f748717284cb9f9f4b12cb6e2c20415acd199e22

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783089/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534357/array-splice-with-a-custom-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I think of is using `array_search()` to get key as offset. Then using `array_merge()` with `array_slice()`

```
$offset = array_search('status', array_keys($columns));
$payment_status = $columns['status'];

$result = array_merge(array_slice($columns, 0, $offset), array('payment_status' => $payment_status), array_slice($columns, $offset, null));
unset($result['status']);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is, to create another array and assign it to your exiting array, this way your original array will be replaced.

```
$newarr = array(
'id' => 'Id',
'payment_status' => 'Payment status',
'created_at' => 'Created At');

$columns = $newarr;
```

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to walk through the entire array only once and create a new array of new columns name.

```
$myArray=array("id"=>123,"status"=>"no paid");
$otherArray = array();
$columns = array(
        'id'=>'Id',
        'status'=>'Status',
        'created_at'=>'Created At'
);


array_map(function($column,$key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key,$GLOBALS['columns']))
        $GLOBALS['otherArray'][$GLOBALS['columns'][$key]]=$column;
    else
        $GLOBALS['otherArray'][$key]=$column;
    return $column;

}, $myArray,array_keys($myArray));
print_r($otherArray);
```

Here is the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa90fb09f0ef8cf6623c35776eb970522cbfe4ad)